# Inner class construction in Java

Tags: java, constructor

I've read about [*class fromal parameters*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.1) and the question then arises as to why the following code is ill-formed?

class `A`:

```
package org.gradle;

public class A extends B.Inner{

    public A(B s){
        s.super(new B()); //error
        s.super();        //OK
    }
}
```

class `B`:

```
package org.gradle;

public class B{

    public class Inner{
    }
}
```

The key part of what was said is:

> The constructor of a non-private inner member class implicitly
>   declares, as the first formal parameter, a variable representing the
>   immediately enclosing instance of the class

So, I expect that besides the default constructor, we should have a constructor with the following signature:

```
Inner(B b);
```

Why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "extra" parameter is effectively hidden from you - both when you declare it, and when you execute it. When you execute it, you provide a value in a different way - in your case, via `s`:

```
s.super();
```

That's passing `s` as the hidden extra argument to the `B.Inner` constructor. The syntax for all of this is a little weird - and I would personally try to avoid using inner classes in this sort of situation... they just get weird very quickly. I usually prefer static nested classes, and if I *do* need an inner class, it's almost always private. Subclassing an inner class declared in a different top-level class is an odd situation, IMO.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not quite clear why can't I explictly invoke that constructor, say, as follows http://ideone.com/igXgCM ? May JLS provide a restrictions I lost?

Comment: @St.Antario: That's just not how inner classes work - you'd use `new B().new Inner()` instead. You're not meant to think of it as like an extra parameter - you're meant to think of it as the instance of the enclosing class used to construct the instance of the inner class.

Comment: Does JLS specify that explcitly?

Comment: @St.Antario: I suspect so, but I can't look for a little while. I suggest you look at both the "inner classes" section and the "constructor invocation" section.

Answer (score 1):

You are already passing the enclosing instance `s` (of class `B`) to the constructor of the inner class when you call `s.super()`, so there's no need to pass another instance of `B`.

The `variable representing the immediately enclosing instance of the class` is an implicit parameter, and it is passed to the constructor using a special syntax.