# Inner class constructor invocation

Tags: java

The **[JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.1)** says:

> The constructor of a non-private inner member class implicitly
>   declares, *as the first formal parameter*, a variable representing the
>   immediately enclosing instance of the class.

---

Ok, if we write the following:

class A:

```
package org.gradle;

public class A extends B.Inner{

    public A(B b){
        b.super();        //OK, invoke B.inner(B)        
    }
}
```

class B:

```
package org.gradle;

public class B{

    public class Inner{
    }
}
```

As said [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26729566/inner-class-construction-in-java/26729644#26729644), `b.super()` actually invoke `B.Inner(B)`.

---

But if we write

class B:

```
package org.gradle;

public class B {
    class Inner{ 
        public Inner(B b){
            System.out.println("Inner(B)");
        }
    }
}
```

class A:

```
package org.gradle;

public class A extends B.Inner{

    public A(B b) {
        b.super(); //The constructor B.Inner() is undefined
    }
}
```

So, in the latter example `b.super()` tries to invoke `B.Inner()` instead. Why is that so difference?

Comment: You need to call `b.super(b)`. The "invisible" first parameter isn't shown in the error message, because it's "invisible".

Comment: @immibis I don't exactly understand what you say. I know how to fix the second example. I want to realise it.

Comment: If you wrote `b.super(5);` in the first example, would you it say "B.Inner(B, int) is undefined" or "B.Inner(int) is undefined"?

Comment: Ok, why in the second example `b.super()` doesn't invoke `B.Inner(B)`, but is in the first does?

Comment: It does try to invoke `B.Inner(B)`.

Comment: @immibis Well, I difined `B.Inner(B)` explictly, but it didn't call.

Comment: Because your `B.Inner(B)` got changed to `B.Inner(B, B)`.

Comment: @immibis It'd be perfect if you provided a normative reference from the JLS, explaining that...

Comment: I don't have one. But if it didn't do that - if it just used your B parameter as the enclosing instance - then it would have the wrong enclosing instance if you used `b.super(new B())`.

Comment: @immibis It sound quite logically, seems to be true. But I'll find that reference anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does try to invoke `B.Inner(B)` in your second example.

It can't find it because there's only a `B.Inner(B, B)`. If your constructor is `B.Inner()` then it gets changed to `Inner(B)`... and if your constructor is `B.Inner(B)` then it gets changed to `B.Inner(B, B)`.

Note that the hidden parameter is effectively an implementation detail, and unless you're studying how the Java compiler works, you don't need to know it exists.